# Vectorized approach for breeding in a genetic algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to encode a single crossover breeding method for a genetic algorithm without an explicit loop. So I need to add one row of an array with and another row of another array with the desired result as seen below. Note that the col_idx arrays choose the particular rows to breed, while the slice index array tells us where to slice (I would like to keep the chunk of the array a up to an including the endpoint).

```
a=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
print('a')
print(a)
a
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
b=np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)*100
print('b')
print(b)
b
[[   0  100  200  300  400]
 [ 500  600  700  800  900]
 [1000 1100 1200 1300 1400]
 [1500 1600 1700 1800 1900]]
row_idx_a=np.array([3,1,0,3,1,3]) #edit-fixed array
row_idx_b=np.array([1,1,0,0,0,3]) #edit-fixed array to fix error identified by the answer below 
slice_idx=np.array([2,1,0,4,4,3])
merged_array=np.zeros((4,5)) ######place holder for final array

#####now some creative slicing magic so that my final array is an irregular indexed addition#######

[[  15   16   17  800  900]
 [   5    6  700  800  900]
 [   0  100  200  300  400]
 [  15   16   17   18   19]
 [   5    6    7    8    9]
 [  15   16   17   18 1900]]
```

I am finding it difficult to vectorize this problem? Any takers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that bits in the expected answer that correspond to the marked numbers

```
                            *
row_idx_a=np.array([3,1,0,3,2,3])
row_idx_b=np.array([2,1,0,0,0,3])
                    *
```

are wrong.

```
np.where(np.less.outer(slice_idx,np.arange(5)),b[row_idx_b],a[row_idx_a])
# array([[  15,   16,   17, 1300, 1400],
#        [   5,    6,  700,  800,  900],
#        [   0,  100,  200,  300,  400],
#        [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19],
#        [  10,   11,   12,   13,   14],
#        [  15,   16,   17,   18, 1900]])
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Yes the marked numbers should be one (I edited the question and noted the correction)